# Complex Equation Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, approximation

Can someone show me how the following two expressions are equivalent:

$$\Gamma = \frac{i X - R_c}{i X + R_c} = -e^{-i 2 \mathrm{tan}^{-1} (\frac{X}{R_c})}$$

I'm working through a calculation and I am not sure how this step is done.

Comment: Has it additional condition, like $X^2+R_c^2=\cdots$ or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Start with $$\Gamma = \frac{i X - R_c}{i X + R_c}=\frac{i X - R_c}{i X + R_c}\times\frac{i X - R_c}{i X - R_c}=\frac{X^2-R_c^2}{X^2+R_c^2}+i\frac{2  R_c X}{X^2+R_c^2}$$ and work with Euler formula and a few trigonometric identities.

Comment: Got it! Thought about doing this soon after posting. Thanks!

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to get some mileage from an argument along the following lines. at least while you seek a more purely algebraic solution

call the two expressions $L(X)$ and $R(X)$ as functions of $X$
$$
L(X) = \frac{i X - R_c}{i X + R_c} \\
R(X) = -e^{-i 2 \mathrm{tan}^{-1} (\frac{X}{R_c})}
$$

then
$$
L' = \frac{2iR_c}{(iX+R_c)^2}
$$
and
$$
R' = \Gamma\frac{d}{dX}\left(-2i\tan^{-1}  \frac{X}{R_c} \right) 
= -2i\frac{\Gamma}{R_c} \frac1{1+\left(\frac{X}{R_c}\right)^2} \\
= \frac{-2iR_c\Gamma}{X^2+R_c^2}
$$
substituting  $\Gamma = -\frac{R_c-i X }{{R_c+i X }}$ shows that $L'=R'$

moreover, the expressions $L(X)$ and $R(X)$ give the same result, $i$, when $X=R_c$